# How to send data from a Custom Rendered Page to a Shared Page in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I've created a custom android render based off of [this code provided by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/contentpage). I have the main Camera Page with shared code. I want to be able to send data (specifically the picture taken) from each of the renders to the main code.

I am not super experienced with Xamarin or C#, but I feel like an event would work for what I'm trying to do the only thing is that I dont know how to reference other page objects.

Any ideas would be super helpful. Thank you!

Comment: You can use messeging center for that

Comment: You're recommended to use Xam.Plugin.Media to get access to device camaras, check https://xamarinhelp.com/use-camera-take-photo-xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 0):

In Renderers `Element` property refers to the shared project object in this case.

Add a variable in each render that is of Base type;

```cs
public class CameraPageRenderer : PageRenderer
{

   ...

   CameraPage FormsPage;

}
```

In each of the renderer method

```cs
protected override void OnElementChanged (VisualElementChangedEventArgs e){

FormsPage= e.NewElement as CameraPage ;
```

And then call method from Shared project element or set its property within Renderer itself.

```cs
FormsPage.CallFooMethod();
FormsPage.Property1 = "some value";
```